# TSQL two Select command one single table output

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

My question is this, after my first `SELECT` block executed I need to check @@`ROWCOUNT` if 0 then execute another `SELECT` block, how can I do that?  Currently I am doing it but getting two table output first one has no or 0 rows and the second table is the one that I want.

```
if(@beta = 1)

BEGIN
SELECT * tblPages
WHERE bitActive = 1
END

if(@@ROWCOUNT = 0)
BEGIN
SELECT * tblPages
WHERE bitActive = 0
END
```

thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
if (select count(1) from tblPages where bitActive = 1) > 0
begin
  select * from tblPages where bitActive = 1
end
else
begin
  select * from tblPages where bitActive = 0
end
```

Comment: I would use `if exists(select * from ...` instead of `count` because it could stop the query when it finds **one** row that matches the where condition. **But** your query, when comparing against `> 0`, has the exact same execution plan as the `exists` version. The query optimizer is smart enough (SQL Server 2008) to realize that you don't actually need to count all rows.